# how to use FIND_IN_SET with dataview.rowfilter in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using this code to filter my datatable by dataview:

```
        Dim xBlockedAccounts As String = "1,5,7"
        Dim xDv_AllAcc As New DataView(MyVar_Dt_Accounts)
        xDv_AllAcc.RowFilter = "FIND_IN_SET(AccID," & xBlockedAccounts & ")"
        Me.Dgv3.DataSource = xDv_AllAcc.ToTable
```

but it gives me that:

> The expression contains undefined function call FIND_IN_SET().'

how I can use FIND_IN_SET function with Rowfilter of Dataview?

Comment: see: [Creating DataView from a LINQ to DataSet Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-dataview-object-linq-to-dataset#creating-dataview-from-a-linq-to-dataset-query)

Comment: What is FIND_IN_SET? Is that a user defined function?

Comment: @TnTinMn thank you, I reviewed it but I don't have experience with LINQ, can you help me how to apply the solution to my code and I need to know the reason why row filter doesn't accept this function.

Comment: @TnTinMn I used this Code: ````Dim query =
        From order In MyVar_Dt_Accounts.AsEnumerable()
        Where order.Field(Of Boolean)("Not FIND_IN_SET(AccID," & xBlockedAccounts & ")")
        Select order

        Dim view As DataView = query.AsDataView()
        Dgv3.DataSource = view

Comment: @TnTinMn but there is a mistake as it says me (Column 'Not FIND_IN_SET(AccID,)' does not belong to table )

Comment: @TnTinMn Can you help me please?

Comment: @Hursey `FIND_IN_SET` is a MySql method. As far as I know, it is not available in .net directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed `MyVar_Dt_Accounts` was a `DataTable`. You need to have an array of blocked accounts values. Then the Linq magic.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim MyVar_Dt_Accounts As New DataTable
    Dim xBlockedAccounts = {"1", "5", "7"}
    Dim dt = (From row As DataRow In MyVar_Dt_Accounts.AsEnumerable
              Select row
              Where xBlockedAccounts.Contains(row("AccID").ToString)).CopyToDataTable
    Dgv3.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Check first that `AccID` is really a string in the database and not a number.